# Can some one give me an example of how to count the no of successful or failure builds of a jenkins using api

Tags: api, jenkins, build, count

I am trying to find a way to count the number of builds successful or failed using an api. As the goal is to build a custom dashboard. Tried GlobaBuildStats and Metrics Plugin but do they offer any endpoints to get the response programaticall?

can any one please help?

Answer (score 0):

One way is you can use the REST API of the Pipeline Stage View Plugin
https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-stage-view-plugin

Once you install the plugin, the metrics will be available at -
<Jenkins_URL>/job/<Job_Name>/wfapi/runs

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped me to find the success or failure at each stage but how do we find the count of the such success or failures at each stage?

Comment: You need to start recording this data in some time series database; I use influxdb for that purpose.

Comment: Yes sir, but I am trying to just see a sample output of the count at each stage success or failed, say for example we have a docker build and push stage, if we run the build say 5 times. And the success of this stage is 5 times as well. I want to print that count, do we find any api or do we have any script to get that out. I hope I am not confusing or asking more

Comment: Hi, what I mean is the data will be available from the API then you can process it and then record in some DB and then visualize using any software of your choice (I use Grafana). Data Extraction > Processing (calculate what you want) > Store > Visualize